# How to add a condition in Javascript for changing the font color depending on the displayed text

Tags: javascript, html, css

im new in JS. How to add font color dependency based on displayed text in Javascript?

There may be several statuses on the displayed page (FREE, RESERVED, SOLD), I would like the dependency to work on any number of displayed statuses on the page. Tried to get `innerText` and `textContent` to display in console, but the fetch only works for single `document.querySelector` and not `document.querySelectorAll` here the console displays `undefined` but in `Nodelist` in console.log is correct `(3)`, and the `innerText` in individual nodes displays correctly: first is `FREE`, second is `RESERVED`, and third is `SOLD`

```
<div class="collection">
  <ul class="list">
   <li class="item"></li>
    <div class="status">FREE
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="item"></li>
    <div class="status">RESERVED
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="item"></li>
    <div class="status">SOLD
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  var status = document.querySelectorAll('.status');

  // Nodelist in console.log is correct (3), and the innerText in individual nodes displays correctly: first is FREE, second is RESERVED, and third is SOLD
 
  // How to add font color dependency based on innerText??
  // status FREE with green color font
  // status RESERVED with orange color font
  // status SOLD with redcolor font

</script>
```

Comment: You already know how to get text, what is holding you now?

Comment: The problem is that there is no problem to change the font color for one status on the page, and I need the function to change every status displayed on this page - it has to collect all statuses and assign them font colors first. I have tried it myself and unfortunately I am at a standstill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// get all statuses
const statuses = document.querySelectorAll('.status')

// define a color for each status
const colors = {
  FREE: 'yellow',
  RESERVED: 'blue',
  SOLD: 'red'
}

statuses.forEach(status => {
  // get timmed text
  const text = status.textContent.trim()
  // get the color
  const color = colors[text]
  // set the color
  status.style.color = color
})
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="status">FREE
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="status">RESERVED
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="status">SOLD
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```